# Grails - How to add Oracle jdbc jar to classpath without placing in /lib?

Tags: oracle, tomcat, grails, grails-2.2

I am attempting to get my grails application running locally with tomcat, but without placing ojdbc6.jar in /lib. My grails application is deployed to Glassfish and works fine on the server (because the ojdbc6.jar is available there). As expected the error is:

```
Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
```

**(Failed) Approach #1**

I first customized my GGTS run-configuration to include the VM arguments:

```
-cp :/somelocalpath/oracle-jdbc-drivers
```

However the error persisted.

**(Failed) Approach #2**

I'm currently looking to use the jvmArgs to point to a local version of the jar.

```
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-cp:/somelocalpath/oracle-jdbc-drivers/ojdbc6.jar"]
```

However a run-war results in:

```
| Error Server failed to start: tomcat exited prematurely with code '1' (error output: 'Unrecognized option: -cp:/apps/glassfish3/oracle-jdbc-drivers/ojdbc6.jar
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
')
```

I should clarify my main focus - I do not want the jar to be included in the final war.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/deployment.html):

> grails.war.resources lets you do any extra processing you want
>   before the WAR file is finally created.

In your case, you need to add something like that to your build config to exclude the Jar of the final WAR.

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
  delete(file:"${ stagingDir }/WEB-INF/lib/yourJarFile.jar")
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up using!